# Extract elements from strings as column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this follows

```
clean.list_raw_id.head(3)
0    {5177, 5178}
1    {2653, 2655}
2          {2793}
```

I want to add a column having values 5177,2653 & 2793

How can I do this in python

I am trying to use apply on the column but its not working

I was able to extract elemnts using the following code

```
[e.strip('{}') for e in clean.list_raw_id[1].split('},{')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first numeric value:

```
df.data = df.data.str.extract("(\d+)")
print (df)
   data
0  5177
1  2653
2  2793
```

Comment: Awesome. This is way better than `findall().apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.str` with `apply`. Given `df`:

```
          data
0  {5177,5178}
1  {2653,2655}
2       {2793}

df.data = df.data.str.findall("\d+").apply(lambda x:x[0])
print(df)
   data
0  5177
1  2653
2  2793
```

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra Thank you for accepting this answer :). However, answer by @jezrael is a better solution which involves less methods and definitely less error prone since `pd.Series.str.extract` will return empty str where as my answer will raise an error. I would appreciate if you mark his/hers answer for the future references :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'vals': [{5177, 5178}, {2653, 2655}, {2793}]})

df['new_col'] = df['vals'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])
```

returns

```
           vals  new_col
0  {5177, 5178}     5177
1  {2653, 2655}     2653
2        {2793}     2793
```